# Do I need a library for Codeigniter to create a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

Do I need an entire library to crate a Facebook app with Codeigniter?  I have not made an app for Facebook before the the developer documentation looked simiple.  Beyond using my "secret" id for my app what else would I need to do to send my output via my view back to the facebook canvas?  Are things more complicated than they seem?  Don't I just output to my view as normal except things go to the canvas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need a library. You can make all requests to the Facebook Graph api using cURL or any other method to call urls.
 However using the Facebook PHP SDK does help, it has a lot of helper methods that you'll find useful, do check [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) link to the documentation for the sdk, it's helpful.
Hope this answer helps you.
p.s: And yeah you just output to your view as any other web app

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not **need** a library, but it will make the process much smoother and take care of a lot of baseline functionality that you will need.

You might [**checkout my post here**](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-facebook-api-with-codeigniter) to see exactly **how** to integrate the offical facebook SDK within a codeigniter application as a stand alone library...